# How this mechanism of value assignment work?

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

I am a **beginner in coding C++**.
I came across this *piece of code*.
I couldn't understand why the ***variable 'a'*** gets assigned ***value 5*** and ***variable 'b'*** gets assigned the ***value 1***.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int a, b;
    a = 5, 2, 3;
    b = (5, 2, 1);

    cout << a<<endl;
    cout << b <<endl;
    cout << a + b;
    return 0;
}
```

The value of
  'a' is 5,
'b' is 1.
But how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work - might be of interest

Comment: Thank for letting me know there is a operator named 'comma operator'.  Learned Something new of interest. Thanks a lot @TomášM.

Comment: How did this come up? What led you to the decision to write code like this?